# Three minipages side by side but over several pages

Tags: page-breaking, minipage

Im searching for a way to typeset the following scenario:
[image: Desired Layout]

With three minipages this works fine:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
    A 1.1
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}\raggedleft
    2 P
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But this won't work with a pagebreak.
So how could I alternatively do this?

BTW: How is it possible to align the text inside the out right minipage with the last line of the minipage in the middle?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `paracol` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
    A 1.1
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}\raggedleft
    2 P
\end{minipage}

\section{paracol}
\columnratio{0.1,0.8,0.1}
\begin{paracol}{3}
    A 1.1
\switchcolumn
    \blindtext
\switchcolumn*
    2 P
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I add an `\dfrac` in the middle column of the three paracols, I get an vertical indentation. How can I avoid this?

[image: minipages vs paracol with inline formula]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
    A 1.1
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$
    \blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}\raggedleft
2 P
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\columnratio{0.1,0.8,0.1}
\begin{paracol}{3}
    A 1.1
\switchcolumn
    $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$
    \blindtext
\switchcolumn
\raggedleft 2 P
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nobody who can give a hint on this?